# isn't Enterprise library a dll?

Tags: iis, configuration

I was given a task to set some machine a web-server host (using IIS).

One of the my TODO list is to verify the following exists on that machine:

1. Enterpraise library
2. Instrumentations tool

How can I verify the first two are installed? (Add/remove program is sufficient?)
I was sure (1) is a MS dll, is there also exe that install all kinds of tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The enterprise library is a set of DLLs.  The file names all start with `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary`.  The DLLs are generally installed in the bin folder of a web application but could be installed in the GAC.  To check if they're in the GAC just open Windows explorer and browse to `%windir%\assembly\` or `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\***`.

I'm not sure what you mean by "Instrumentations tool".  If it's also a DLL, you'll be checking the same places.  You just need to know what DLLs you're looking for.

It's probably also worth mentioning - you can "install" the enterprise library on a computer.  There is an MSI installer you can download.  This is normally not done on a production server.  You need to deploy the DLLs with your app (e.g. in the bin folder) or in the GAC.  That installer does neither of those things for you.  Typically you'd run the installer on a developer machine so that Visual Studio can find the DLLs.  However, it does include the "Enterprise Library Configuration" utility.  If that's what you're looking for you can check your start menu.  You'd find it under:

Microsoft patterns & practices\Enterprise Library X.X\Enterprise Library Configuration.

Comment: thanks, the installer help visual studio find the dlls, how come if they are not deployed? or you mean the installer is complementary to the deploy?